# Migration from GWT to Angular 2 : server-side architecture

Tags: angular, rest, web-services

I'm trying to migrate a CRUD app from GWT to Angular 2. The app is consuming a REST web service which is not exposed to the Internet.

In GWT, the web service calls were made from the server side and pushed to the client through RPC.

Now, since Angular will be the client side (only), and since I can't call directly the web service from outside, I'm wondering what is the best way to do it.

My first though is to build a Java back-end hosted with Angular (on the same server). Angular will communicate with the Java back-end (with a rest service) and Java back-end will consume the REST web service.

All the architectures I've found assume that the REST web service can be accessed directly. I'd be really interested if someone have faced the same issue with a javascript client technology (Angular, React or Vue.js). Also, can "server side rendering" (SSR) help here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Found my answer in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560421/angularjs-server-side-architecture). Thanks.